# QKD BB84 protocol: Is confirmation of the qubit possible? Or does the two generals problem apply?

Tags: quantum-computing

In the Quantum Key Distribution protocol BB84, Alice sends x qubits to Bob. There is no acknowledgement of receipt. This cannot be done over the quantum channel. If I need an acknowledgement, it must be sent via a classical channel. But that means that I am sending two messages independently of each other, which brings us to the two generals problem.
Do I understand this correctly? Or am I missing something that could help me confirm the transmission similarly to TCP?

Answer (score 0):

From  Laudenbach paper `Continuous-Variable Quantum Key Distribution with Gaussian Modulation - The Theory of Practical Implementations`:

> Quantum key distribution is a method to generate a secret key between
> two distant parties, Alice and Bob, based on transmitting
> non-orthogonal quantum states. After the transmission and measurement
> of these quantum states, Alice and Bob exchange classical messages and
> perform post-processing to generate a secure key. In order to prevent
> a man-in-the-middle attack, Alice and Bob need to authenticate these
> classical messages in advance (so strictly speaking QKD is a
> key-growing protocol).

So BB84 works only if you have an authenticate classical channel. I guess this assumption ends the Two Generals' Problem. Am I right?